# Injecting class into derivation

Tags: c++, templates, derived-class

I'm struggling with a piece of code and at this point I'm questioning if what I'm trying to achieve is even possible.

Below is the code of the various DLL and the actual piece of code that's giving me an headache

First DLL:

```
// DLL_A
// This DLL is the main SDK which gives me the capability to create and manage extensions
class IViewportExtensionBase
{
public:
    virtual ~IViewportExtensionBase();
    ...
};

template<typename ExtensionType>
class IViewportExtension : public IViewportExtensionBase
{
protected:
    IViewportExtension()
        : IViewportExtensionBase(ExtensionType::_GetName())
    { }
};

class ExtensionsManager
{
public:
    static IViewportExtensionBase* GetExtension(const std::string& extensionName)
    {
        return _extensions[extensionName];
    }

private:
    std::unordered_map<std::string, IViewportExtensionBase*> _extensions;
};
```

Second DLL:

```
// DLL_B
// This is another library of the SDK which links DLL_A to add a custom capabilities to the extensions
class ViewportExtensionAdditions
{
public:
    virtual ~ViewportExtensionAdditions()
    { }

    virtual void CustomAddition()
    { }
};

template<typename ExtensionType>
class ICustomViewportExtension : public IViewportExtension<ExtensionType>, public ViewportExtensionAdditions
{ };
```

Extension DLL

```
// DLL_EXTENSION
// This DLL contains the actual extension which implements the interface defined by DLL_B 8of course this links DLL_B too)
class ViewportExtension_A : public ICustomViewportExtension<ViewportExtension_A>
{
public:
    void CustomAddition() override;
    ...
}
```

Actual program giving me the error:

```
// This is a piece of code of the final program which loads the extensions and then tries to call the custom capabilities added by DLL_B
// This program knows about the headers of both DLL_A and DLL_B and links them, but it doesn't know about the headers of DLL_EXTENSION which 
// is dynamically loaded by the extensions manager
auto extension = (ViewportExtensionAdditions*)ExtensionsManager::GetExtension("ViewportExtension_A");
if (extension != nullptr)
{
    // This call doesn't work, meaning that is never calls the overridden method in ViewportExtension_A
    // but calls some other method which looks like the virtual table is somewhat off
    extension->CustomAddition();
}
```

I'm afraid that deriving a class injecting another (what I'm doing in DLL_B) and then casting to that other class (what I'm doing in the acqual program) is not possible.

If actually turns out it's not possible, what could be a way to achieve what I'm trying to do?

Comment: `ViewportExtensionAdditions` is not derived from `IViewportExtensionBase`, so you are not allowed to use the cast `(ViewportExtensionAdditions*)`. Did you intend to cast to `ViewportExtension_A*` instead? Also, you probably meant `_extensions` to be `static`.

Comment: Yes, `_extensions` should be static, I modified the code to remove unuseful stuff and I missed that. Anyway, I can't cast to `ViewportExtension_A*` since the program doesn't include the extension's headers, it just loads the DLL.

Comment: I am not sure I completely understand the question, but I guess you want to `dynamic_cast` to `ViewportExtensionAdditions` then?

Comment: mmm...not really. Anyway, after taking a pause and looking again at the code I found that I can actually derive from `IViewportExtensionBase` and throw this all idea of the injection to the trash...